# What is the output when green laser pointer pump diode is replaced by a CD burner laser pump diode

Tags: photons, laser, crystals

I was wondering what happens if CD burner photons hit the crystal NdYO4 and KTP 780 nm wave length where original 808 nm IR pumper diode. I am confused with NdYO4 crystal I know that KTP is a frequency doubler what is the new output wavelength ??

**Please look at the image below to see how green laser pointer works**

*Laser pump diode is at the corner orginal 808 nm afterwards 780 nm

CD burner laser pump diode

[image]

[image]

([image source](https://www.quora.com/Whats-inside-laser-pointers))

Comment: This is a confusing question, since the setup is not clear (I can guess something, but I'm not sure I've got quite what the OP asks).

Comment: Look at the image url I just putted it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on in your laser pointer is the 808 nm pump laser is used as an optical pump source for the yttrium vanadate (Nd:YVO<sub>4</sub>) laser, producing 1064 nm.

The 1064 nm output of the Nd:YVO<sub>4</sub> laser is being doubled in the KTP crystal to produce ~532 nm green output light.

If you replace the pump laser with one at a different wavelength, the device might work weakly, or possibly not at all.

First, the new laser wavelength won't pump the Nd:YVO4 crystal efficiently it it does at all. As you can see in this energy level diagram for the Nd<sup>3+</sup> ion, the transistions used are fairly specific to the 808 or 869 nm pump source:

[image]

([image source](https://www.rp-photonics.com/neodymium_doped_gain_media.html))

So most of your new source's light will likely just pass through the Nd:YVO4 crystal without effect.

When it reaches the KTP crystal, I'm unsure what will happen, but even if your new wavelength is within the frequency doubling band of KTP, the geometry of the crystal is critical to efficient SHG. Mainly you need to arrange that the pump beam and SHG beam experience the same index of refraction so they remain in phase. According to [this](http://www.newlightphotonics.com/Nonlinear-Optical-Crystals/KTP-Crystals) the range to do that is 994-3600 nm. To operate outside that band requires a more complex arrangement such as a [periodically poled](https://www.rp-photonics.com/periodic_poling.html) crystal. If your KTP crystal is tuned for 1064 nm input light, it won't operate well (or at all) with whatever new wavelength you are applying.

So I'd expect you to just get your new laser wavelength as output of the pointer, probably not very well collimated, or perhaps very widely diverging, since the optics in the laser pointer are also not arranged for your new configuration.

Comment: Your answer is clear and perfect, I hope this question is visible to others again

Comment: Where did you take 503 nm and 502 nm figures? 1064/2=532, not any of your two numbers.

Comment: @Ruslan, I think the first was a typo, and the 2nd one was mixing up the input and output wavelengths.

Comment: @ThePhoton Seems like the green laser pointers don't work at cold temperatures, meaning the energy gap seems to change in the crystal do you think will it work in different temperature for cd burner laser pump diode 780 nm? https://youtu.be/9tOcUyakk0Q